# Download Flock browser in command line

Tags: 10.04, command-line

Is Flock browser available in Ubuntu 10.4. If so how do I download in command line. Is it perhaps:

sudo apt get Flock browser

Not sure, will appreciate some help. Thnxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably not available in the core repositories:

```
apt-cache search flock
```

returns nothing like that on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: Thanks. Did a bit of browsing and found that Ubuntu needs to be prepared for Flock first with: sudo apt-get install libstdc++5

Comment: @namkid: You may want to consider documenting your steps to setup Flock as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

From the commandline I would do (using GetDeb-Packages):

```
sudo bash -c "echo deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu lucid-getdeb apps games >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
wget -q http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key -O- | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo aptitude install flock
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

`wget http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/flock/releases/2.0.3/l10n/en-CA/flock-2.0.3.en-CA.linux-i686.tar.bz2`

Unpack and follow the installation instructions.

(That's en-CA for Canadian English; there are different localizations.)

Answer (score 1):

I've written up a how-to previously, [here](http://amysramblings.wordpress.com/2009/05/24/how-to-install-flock-on-ubuntu/).

You'll have to install libstdc++5 so it works properly.